# How to compute $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^3(x)+ \cos^3(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> How to compute the following integral?
> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^3(x)+ \cos^3(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

So what I did is to change $\sin(x)$ to $\cos(x)$ with cofunction identity, which is $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} -x) = \cos(x)$. The integral changes into easier:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^3(x)+ \cos^3(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

And then I divided by $\cos^3(x)$. It will turn everything to

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^2(x)}{\tan^3(x)+1} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

And I used $u$-substitution setting $u = \tan(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm{d}u = \sec^2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and the bounds $u = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty$ and $u =\tan(0) = 0$ and the integral changed into integral to

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^3} $$

This is where I used partial fraction decomposition and my answer is divergent and my answer is wrong:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3(u+1)} + \frac{-u+2}{3(u^2-u+1)} \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

by this it looks like it will divergent.

The correct answer is $\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$. So, what do I do, next?

Then I did the another method which gives me divergent again,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{1+\tan^3(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

and $u = \tan(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm{d}u = \sec^2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$, the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{u}{1+u^3} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{-1}{3(u+1)} + \frac{u+1}{3(u^2-u+1)} \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

and did partial fraction and this gives divergent.

I have no idea what to do next for the first method of work, or the second method of work.

Comment: Well, in both cases the integral you wrote converges for rather standard reasons. Maybe you should show us how you used partial fraction decomposition in one (or both) of the methods.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you have already shown that the integral is equal to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^3}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u\,\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^3},$$ and so, the integral also equals the arithmetic average of these two, i.e., $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+u}{1+u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-u+u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$ The last integral only requires completing the square of the denominator.

Comment: let me re-edit again...showing my PFD

Comment: @SangchulLee, I re-edit it

Comment: @Espace'etale, I re-edit it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761054/how-to-evaluate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-x-sin2n1x-cos2n1x-dx/3761056#3761056)

For all $n\geq 2$ we shall show that

> $$I(n)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{\sin^{2n-1}x+\cos^{2n-1}x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}\operatorname{csc}\left(\frac{(2\pi(n-k-1)}{2n-1}\right)$$. Just set $n=2$ we have $$I(1)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}dx =\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$$.

---

Call original integral as $I_1$ After we were done with $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ we have $$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x +\cos^3x }dx $$ adding the $I_1$ and $I_2$ we have $$I= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x+\cos x }{\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^2x-\tan x +1}dx\underbrace {=}_{\tan x=y} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dy}{y^2-y+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\bigg|_0^{\infty}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt 3} $$

Answer (score 9):

Note

\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^3} 
&=\frac13
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+u}+ \frac{2-u}{u^2-u+1}\right)du\\
&= \frac13\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+u}-\frac12 \frac{2u-1}{u^2-u+1}+ \frac32\frac1{(u-\frac12)^2+\frac34} \right)du\\
&=\frac13 \left( \ln\frac{u+1}{\sqrt{u^2-u+1}}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{2u-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}
\end{align}

Comment: does the $\infty$ divergent it?

Comment: @EM4, We have $$\lim_{u\to\infty}\log\frac{u+1}{\sqrt{u^2-u+1}}=\log\left(\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u+1}{\sqrt{u^2-u+1}}\right)=\log(1)=0.$$ So the two log terms $\log(u+1)$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\log(u^2-u+1)$, each of which diverges as $u\to\infty$, cancel out each other to give a finite and nice value!

Comment: I should have known, I forgot the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Your first method, setting $u=\tan x$, is the substitution suggested by *Bioche's rules*  Your problem is that there's an error in you computation. You should obtain the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\color{red}u\,\mathrm du}{1+u^3},$$
which is convergent since $\:\frac u{1+u^3}\sim_\infty\frac1{u^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of substituting $y=\tan x$, consider

$$\begin{align*}
y=\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x} &\iff \tan x=\frac{1-y}{1+y} \\
& \implies x = \arctan\frac{1-y}{1+y} =  \frac\pi4-\arctan y & (y>-1)\\
& \implies \sin x = \frac{1-y}{\sqrt2\sqrt{1+y^2}} \text{ and } \cos x = \frac{1+y}{\sqrt2\sqrt{1+y^2}}
\end{align*}$$

which does a better job of simplifying the integrand:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\sin x}{\sin^3x + \cos^3x} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\frac{1-y}{\sqrt2\sqrt{1+y^2}}}{\frac{(1-y)^3}{2\sqrt2\,(1+y^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{(1+y)^3}{2\sqrt2\,(1+y^2)^{3/2}}} \, \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2-2y}{2+6y^2} \, dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{2\,dy}{1+3y^2} = \boxed{\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}}
\end{align*}$$